# UFW with NAT : Need to block all NAT requests except to one IP with out cutting NAT server from internet. Is this possible?

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, ufw

I have a small cluster of kiosks using a single RPi for bootp, dhcp, dns, radius, and nat to the internet.  The RPi4 running RPi version of Ubuntu 18.04.

What I am struggling with is building a configuration a UFW rule(s) to block all NAT requests from private network out to the internet except for one IP address.

My first attempt to block the external interface failed, as it blocked the NAT server from getting outside.

is there a way to build a rule like this? For example, allow all NAT to 1.1.1.1. Internal LAN with NAT interface is using eth0, the WAN is using eth1.

```
ufw deny in on eth0 to eth1 outgoing
ufw allow in on eth0 to [eth1 ip 1.1.1.1] port 443 proto tcp
```

Comment: What do you mean by NAT **requests**?  NAT requests don't automatically get processed unless you have UPnP set up which is an atypical setup.  (UFW is also not a complex enough tool to do complex NAT stuff like this)

Comment: the internal network uses the RPi as relay, I might have been using the wrong term.  I am using a simple sysctl.conf with routing enabled, and IPTables configuration I spotted for NAT routing. close to this: https://gist.github.com/cellularmitosis/8294f0800e6d4b4022772fe8869d8a6f